# I need to inflate a RecyclerView inside a Fragment AndroidStudio

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, tabs, fragment

I would like to use a Tab/Fragment to show RecyclerView, but I don't know how to do it because the method of the Fragment class return a View, not a Reclycler View:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_needs, container, false);

        return myFragmentView;
    }
```

The code of the fragment.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NeedsFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/all_user_need_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your `onCreateView()` method makes no sense:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_needs, container, false);

    return needsFragmentRecyclerView; //you should be returning myFragmentView here, not whatever needsFragmentRecyclerView is
}
```

Second, once you inflate your layout, just use `findViewById()`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_needs, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_need_list); //assign to a global variable if needed

    return myFragmentView; //replaced with the proper variable
}
```

Alternatively, you can get the RecyclerView from anywhere in your Fragment, as long as it's called *after* `onCreateView()` with the following:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.all_user_need_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return any type of view component and Custom view that is inherit from android.view class in onCreateView() method.